# Change line comment mark for a given language

Tags: notepad++

When I comment out lines (**Edit** -> **Comment/Uncomment** -> **Single-line comment**, or <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>) in VBS, Notepad++ inserts `REM` as the comment marker. I would prefer to have the `'` inserted. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Notepad++ inserts REM as the comment marker. I would prefer to have '

1. Open the Notepad++ language config file "langs.xml"
2. Find `<Language name="vb" ext="vb vbs" commentLine="REM" commentStart="" commentEnd="">`
3. Change `commentLine="REM"` to `commentLine="'"`
4. Save changes
5. Restart Notepad++

Source [Change comment character in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259865/3536342) by [rafiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226989/rafiki)

---

#### Where can I find langs.xml?

`langs.xml` can been found in the `%APPDATA%` directory if you are using an installed version of Notepad++, and in the Notepad++ directory if you are using the portable version.

Comment: @ZevSpitz removed ...